# A non well formed numeric value encountered for number_format

Tags: php, html

When using number format to updated the value in invoice, I've got a non well formed numeric value error message.

```
$amount = number_format($_POST['amount'], 2);
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `$_POST['amount']` without and with `number_format` and the error

Comment: Sure, i used to send this value in AJAX. Before posting the value, i have made an alert that will return 400.

Comment: The error is? post all code

Comment: Error A non well formed numeric value encountered
Line 32
`$amount = number_format($_POST['amount'], 2); // We need to manually add the .00 for cents.`

Comment: try `$amount = number_format( (int) $_POST['amount'], 2);`

Comment: _"i have made an alert that will return 400"_ - That's not from PHP though? Or did you output the value in PHP and alerted the response from PHP in your ajax callback? If not, what does `var_dump($_POST['amount']);` (in PHP) output? It could also be something silly as a trailing space after the number.

Comment: Yeah make sense, I have update the JavaScript before posting AJAX. please check the updated answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the JavaScript to validate the amount using isNaN()

```
 var amount = $('#invoiceAmount').val();
    if(isNaN(amount)){
    alert ('Please enter in the valid amount.');
    } else 
    // post values by AJAX
    }
```

Comment: isNaN() – Stands for “is Not a Number”, if variable is not a number, it return true, else return false.